# OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: apache, ssl

Standing up a web server, got the error code in the subject when I tried 
`sudo wget -v https://192.168.0.2`
but I get my index.html if I do 
`sudo wget -v http://192.168.0.2:443`
Every thread I have read says that it's because HTTP is listening on 443 and blocking SSL from using it and I confirmed that with 
`sudo openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.2:443 -debug`

Using CentOS 7

***EDIT #1: tried to post configs, but Ctrl+K isn't formatting my code.  Ask for specific lines of a config file, will post in a comment.***

1. /etc/hosts
2. /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
3. /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
4. /etc/httpd/conf.d/non-ssl.conf
5. /etc/httpd/sites-available/mysite.conf

Tried these threads already:

- [SSL connection error:140770FC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164088/ssl-connection-error140770fc)
- [error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135637/error140770fcssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol)
- [SMTPS: OpenSSL - SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol s23_clnt.c:787:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449946/smtps-openssl-ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol-s23-clnt-c)
- [file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)

If I missed a thread, please let me know, and I'll try anything.

Comment: *"Every thread I have read says that it's because HTTP is listening on 443"*- which is very likely the case. This means that the configuration is wrong and you need to provide **all** the config files instead of only describing what they do in your opinion.

Comment: "unknown protocol" means the remote end does not speak TLS at all. Start with `httpd -S` that should really show you the VirtualHost defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patrick-Mevzek gave a useful troubleshooting tool.  httpd -S pointed to the config file that was causing the problems.  I changed the port from 443 to 80 in my /etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.conf file (a file I forgot about), and everything worked fine (minus the SSL problems, but I'm working through that).  Thanks to Patrick!